# Como passar vários parâmetros pra query no mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Estou querendo fazer uma busca no Mongodb com Mongoose (NodeJs), onde eu quero os objetos cujo atributo url que é uma string contenha dentro de si pelo menos 1 dos valores que eu tenho num array. Como eu poderia fazer isso, usando apenas 1 find()?

Por exemplo:
Objeto salvo no Mongo:
{url:"www.site.com.br/?laranja?...}

```
const chavesDeBusca = [laranja, melancia]
const query =  model.find({url: 1 ou mais valore de chavesDeBusca})
```

Obviamente esse código acima não funciona, mas a ideia é fazer isso.

Eu poderia usar uma regex como valor da chaveDeBusca.
Mas não estou conseguindo montar uma que faça isso. Por exemplo:essa regex faria o seguinte:  "dá match se uma string contém  um ou mais elementos contidos no array chaveDeBusca"

Será que o '$in' resolve? Aparentemente não, pois o resultado da busca vem vazio, mesmo depois de eu dar exec()

Ideias?

Answer (score 2):

Pode usar o operador [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/).

```
const chavesDeBusca = ['laranja', 'melancia']
// cria a query
const query = model.find({ 'atributo': {'$in' : chavesDeBusca } })

// resolver os resultados utilizando then
query.then((error, documents)=> {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(erro)
    }
    // resultados iteraveis em documents
})

// resolver os resultados usando await exec()
// o await tem que estar contido em uma async function
const documents = await query.exec();
// espera pelos resultados e executa a proxima linha
console.log(documents)
```

---

**Edit:**
Use o operador [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/)

```
const chavesDeBusca = ['laranja', 'melancia']

// mapear o array de busca para `$or`
const chavesDeBuscaMapeado = chavesDeBusca.map(chave => ({
    'atributo' : new RegExp(`.*${chave}.*`, 'ig')
}))
// cria a query
const query = model.find({ '$or' : chavesDeBuscaMapeado })
```

Comment: To testando aqui. Mas pra quer serve esse exec()? Eu li na documentação mas não tá claro. O .find() já não retorna os objetos resultantes da query?

Comment: @LucasPletsch Eu uso muito promises o `exec` ira retornar uma `Promise`, pode correr a query de tal foma `const query = await mode.find(...).exec()` dentro de uma funcão `async`

Comment: se eu não boto o exec, então a chamada ao método find() bloqueia a execução do meu programa? Ou seja, é feita de forma síncrona?

Comment: @LucasPletsch nao o `find` nao bloqueia, qualquer das chamadas retorna um `thenable` apenas o `exec` retorna uma `Promise` verdadeira. depende da arquitetura do seu projeto. Eu perfiro usar `Promises` :)

Comment: Então se eu faço simplesmente   const query =  model.find({ 'atributo': {'$in' : chavesDeBusca } })   e tento acessar essa constante query na  linha imediatamente abaixo, ela pode estar vazia, ou ainda sem o resultado da busca?

Comment: @LucasPletsch E bem possivel para queries mais complexas ou com muitos resultados, Eu recomendo usar `await`  `exec`. Irei atualizar a minha resposta com mais detalhes.

Comment: Ah. Eu me confundo com await. Mas posso fazer simplesmente model.find().then((err, docs) =>{ faz algo com os docs  } também né

Comment: @LucasPletsch Perfeitamente! qualquer das formas esta correta! :) atualizei a resposta com mais detalhes

Comment: Ao dar console.log(documents) não imprime nada, aí eu dei um console.log(typeof documents) e disse que era um object. Aí eu dei um Object.values(documents) e também não imprimiu nada. Mas porque não tem nada dentro? Minha busca deu errado?

Comment: Na verdade assim. O valor do atributo no banco de dados é uma url no formato de string. Então, o valor do atributo inteiroo nunca vai ser "Laranja". Mas pode ser www.google.com/laranja/suco, por exemplo. O '$in' ainda retornaria esse objeto?

Comment: Vou alterar a pergunta

Comment: Se o valor no banco de dados não é exatamente o valor de busca de facto essa query retorna um objeto vazio, pode entao usar o operador `$or` mapeando o array de pesquisa, vou atualizar a resposta com mais detalhes